# Travis-CI error: installing nloptr pkg (r pkg check)

Tags: url, travis-ci, nlopt

I try to use travis-ci to check whether my r package is correct. My package should import r pkg `nloptr`. And travis-ci will give the error in "r": "oldrel" branch. I show error here:

```
configure: Need to download and build NLopt
trying URL 'http://ab-initio.mit.edu/nlopt/nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz'
Warning in download.file(url = "http://ab-initio.mit.edu/nlopt/nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz",  :
  "internal" method cannot handle https redirection to: 'https://github.com/stevengj/nlopt/releases/download/nlopt-2.4.2/nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz'
switching to method = "libcurl" because of redirection to https
downloaded 0 bytes
Warning in download.file(url = "http://ab-initio.mit.edu/nlopt/nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz",  :
  URL 'https://github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com/12412122/5dd09f0a-6d59-11e7-9685-af3ea1aac9be?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20180127%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180127T205849Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=e6604ca4110973e167461335f8ffe6e340882219fd2a4ebc2a6065d4e416cc2e&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dnlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream': status was '403 Forbidden'
Error in download.file(url = "http://ab-initio.mit.edu/nlopt/nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz",  : 
  cannot download all files
Execution halted
/bin/tar: This does not look like a tar archive
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
/bin/tar: Child returned status 1
/bin/tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Warning message:
In untar(tarfile = "nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz") :
  '/bin/tar -xf 'nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz'' returned error code 2
configure: Starting to install library to /tmp/RtmpCm39nC/R.INSTALL37f361a5b719/nloptr/nlopt-2.4.2
./configure: line 3325: cd: nlopt-2.4.2: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the following to your `.travis.yml` as it will work in either container-based or standard infrastructures while the answer by Chaoran Hu only works for standard infrastructures:

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - libnlopt-dev
```

See the travis docs for the why this answer will work more generally: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r/#APT-packages

Comment: Definitely, Luke give us a more professional suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem is travis-ci do not know how to install this `nlopt`, which is needed by r pkg `nloptr`. (travis-ci can not download `nlopt` by the given url.) Fortunately, we can tell travis-ci another way by adding this code to `.travis.yml` file, which helps travis-ci to install nlopt by another way.

```
apt_packages:
  - libnlopt-dev
```

Now, travis-ci can serve you well!